# Animating bars to width of Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am creating a nav bar for my website and I want the slide outs to animate to the width of whatever text is inside it I also want everything on one line. Here is the jsfiddle and my jquery code so far

http://jsfiddle.net/2UEpd/26/
$(document).ready(function () {

```
$("#test").hide();
$(".title").hide();



$(".home").click(function (){
    $("#test").slideToggle("slow");
});

$(".slideWrapper").hover(

function () {     
    $(this).children(".slideNav:eq(0)").stop().animate({
        width: "112px",
        height: "30px"
    });

    $(this).children(".slideBox:eq(0)").stop().animate({
        left: "112px",
        opacity: "1"
    });

    $(this).find(".title").show();


}, function () {
    var $box = $(this).children(".slideBox:eq(0)");

    $(this).children(".slideNav:eq(0)").stop().animate({
        width: "0px",
        height: "30px"

    });

    $(this).children(".slideBox:eq(0)").stop().animate({
        left: "0px",
        opacity: ".7"
    });

    $(this).find(".title").hide();

});
```

});

I've been trying for a while now, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Display:table` propertie or `inline-block` would help.

An  idea would be to play width `text-indent` and `letter-spacing` for instance.

Here a sample of the idea via CSS only,  using table-layout properties so container fits to width used by its content text. http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kaEoe

basicly:

```
.slideNav {
  height: 30px;
  width: 0px;
  padding:0 15px;/* gives it 30px width minimal */
  line-height:30px;
  display:table;/* shrink /expand to size needed by content */
  position: relative; 
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-indent:-3em;
  letter-spacing:-1em;  
  transition:1s; linear ;
  opacity: .7;
  color: transparent;
}
.slideNav:hover {/* here set back to regular setting to layout text properly */
  opacity:1;
  text-indent:0em;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  color: white;
}
```

*the toggle click close/open feature on menu is driven via :focus and pointer-events for demo prpose. javaScript should take care of this for a better/good practice.*